# How to block incoming emails that have a blank to field and a zip attachment?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, microsoft-office-365

My company has been dealing with some viruses lately and I noticed a pattern in all of them has been that they are sent with every recipient in the "bcc:" field and an empty "to:" field along with a zip file attachment. We currently use exchange 2010 and have Exchange Online Protection.

So far we have been dealing with it by blocking the attachment file name as soon as we see the email come in, but I really would like a more proactive approach.

I tried to create a rule in EOP to delete all emails where the recipient address matches any text patterns: "^$" and any attachment's file extension matches "zip", but it isn't blocking any of my test emails.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any other rules? Have you run a message trace to confirm no rules are overriding your new rule?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may want to use the particular predicate **AnyOfToHeader**.  [Technet Article for reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638183(v=exchg.141).aspx).

My bigger question is: Why is this junk getting through EOP?  I occasionally get documents with macros inside archives, but typically EOP is quick to filter out recurrences of these items.

I have taken a different approach in my tenant with regard to ZIP/RAR/7z archives.  I have a transport rule that delivers [items containing ZIP/RAR/7z] to an administrative mailbox instead of the user, so I may review the contents and deliver to the end user.  This results in a delay to the end user, but it is less impactful than cryptolocker or some nonsense going around our file shares.

Exchange Online (which is plainly not your operating environment) is due to have a [feature release](http://roadmap.office.com/en-us#I-141-8863) coming up that will allow notification of an end user when a transport rule is met.  I intend to use this to generate an email and generate a service request in our ITSM solution.

Comment: I'm not sure why EOP hasn't been catching these. I added a rule today to prevent all exe and scr files from coming in, but I was wondering about a differentway to block them. It sounds like blocking the blank to field is an overly complicated way of doing it. I personally would love to block all zip files as attachments, but that is unfortunately not an option for the business. Thanks for the advice. I will take a look at that predicate.

Comment: As an anecdote, I actually receive some valid mail with ZIP attachments, and recipients in the BCC: field.  It's annoying as hell because my first instinct is to trash them!

Comment: I would run the "redirect ZIP for security review" option by your business.  I implemented the policy out of necessity, and your business users might be amenable to a similar workflow if you can establish an SLA.

Comment: Anecdote: today I had a dozen trojan-infected ZIP files come through before EOP started detecting them.  A further two-dozen or so notifications of detection came through.  It turns out my initial submissions were not attached to my live id, so I won't be getting comprehensive reporting there.